# Retrieving data from formdata in PHP from AJAX

Tags: php

I'm trying to send an image via AJAX to my API via formdata, which then gets passed to a couple of functions to create an image post. The PHP however is throwing out an unidentified index error... and I can't see why.

I generate my formdata with this

```
var fd = new FormData();
var files = $('#FileInput')[0].files[0];
var user = <?php echo $user_id; ?>;
var bodytext = $("#PostBox").val();
fd.append('file', files);
fd.append('user_id', user);
fd.append('body', bodytext);
```

Then, send it via AJAX...

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "api/createimgpost",
  processData: false,
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: fd,
  success: function(r) {
 console.log(r)
  //location.reload();
        },
  error: function(r) {
   console.log(r)
});
```

Then retrieve via PHP to pass the data on to my functions...

```
else if ($_GET['url'] == "createimgpost")
        {
            $user_id = Login::isLoggedIn();
            $poster_id = $_POST['user_id'];

            if ($user_id == $poster_id)
            {           
                $body = isSet($_POST['body']);
                $imgForm = isSet($_FILES['file']);

                $img = Images::Upload($imgForm);

                Post::CreateImgPost($img, $body, $user_id);
            }
        }
```

In my network tab, it looks like the Form is sent off just fine...

```
------WebKitFormBoundarybBk6iZXXDNWy6L3K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="DefaultHeader.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundarybBk6iZXXDNWy6L3K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_id"

1
------WebKitFormBoundarybBk6iZXXDNWy6L3K
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="body"

asdasdasdasd
------WebKitFormBoundarybBk6iZXXDNWy6L3K--
```

But I'm still getting an unidentified index error on user_id (and I'd assume body and file too). Am I missing something simple? Still kinda a noobie here...

Comment: Assuming is a big mistake when you are programming in any language. Confirm your expected values and rule them out.

Comment: I commented out the user_id line and got the same unidentified index on body and file too :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `contentType:` to `contentType: false,`

Also

Your checks should look similar to this:

```
if( ! isset( $_GET['url'] ) ){ // if $_GET['url'] is not set
    echo 'No URL Set';
    die();
}
if ($_GET['url'] == "createimgpost"){

    if( ! isset( $_POST['user_id'] ) ){ // if $_POST['user_id'] is not set
        echo 'No User ID Set';
        die();
    }

    $user_id = Login::isLoggedIn();

    if ( $user_id != $_POST['user_id'] ){
        echo 'No User ID Doesnt Match';
        die();
    }
    if( ! isset( $_POST['body'] ) ){ // if $_POST['body'] is not set
        echo 'No Body Set';
        die();
    }   
    if( ! isset( $_FILES['file'] ) ){ // if $_FILES['file'] is not set
        echo 'File Not Set';
        die();
    }
    if( $_FILES['file']['error'] !==0 ){ // if $_FILES['file'] has errors
        echo $_FILES['file']['error'];
        die();
    }

    $img = Images::Upload( $_FILES['file'] );
    Post::CreateImgPost( $img , $_POST['body'] , $user_id );
    //run checks on your POST creation. Whatever it returns for success

    echo 'Success';
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I was planning on adding more checks (And it was helpful to see how you've laid it out), but am just building in the basic functionality right now. If I were to add the check it would just return the No User Set message because I know it's giving the undefined index error.

Comment: That's the point of the checks, it tells you where the errors are coming from and you can work back, no assuming. Try updating your Ajax `contentType` to `contentType: false,`

Comment: That was it! Thank you! Once I did that the errors got a lot more specific and it was just a couple of syntax errors after that.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted, I updated my answer to include the content type, you should mark it as solved so it can help others.